# Image is not uploading in WordPress dashboard

Tags: wordpress, image-uploading

When I try to upload the image through media, it shows some error in WordPress. The image is not uploading in the WordPress dashboard.

[image]

Comment: Please check the folder permission for upload folder. Change it to 777

Comment: how could i set it to 777. I have not seen the permission when i right click the folder

Comment: As you are using Windows Server, please set permission to folder with Write, Read, Executable.

Comment: Please change the permission wp-content recursively.

Comment: Iam using htdocs xampp apache server. please give me suggestions how to do it